# How can I add the listener to my symbol on MapBox android map?

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I have MapBox APi. but in the last update API deleted markers from MapBox class. Haw can I select my added symbols and start events?

```
override fun onMapReady(mapboxMap: MapboxMap) {
    this.mapBoxMap = mapboxMap
    val query = Query()
    query.getAllParking { parking ->
        allParking = parking
            this.mapBoxMap.setStyle(
                Style.DARK
            ) { map ->
                // добавляем метку на карту
                map.addImage(
                    "marker-icon-id",
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        this.resources,
                        R.drawable.mapbox_marker_icon_default
                    )
                )
                parking.forEach {
                    try {
                        val geoJsonSource = GeoJsonSource(
                            it.Parking_id,
                            Feature.fromGeometry(
                                Point.fromLngLat(
                                    it.Parking_longitude.toDouble(),
                                    it.Parking_latitude.toDouble()
                                )
                            )
                        )
                        map.addSource(geoJsonSource)
                    } catch (ex: NumberFormatException) {
                        print(ex.localizedMessage)
                    }
                    val symbolLayer = SymbolLayer(it.Parking_id, it.Parking_id)
                    symbolLayer.withProperties(PropertyFactory.iconImage("marker-icon-id"))
                    map.addLayer(symbolLayer)
                }
                enableLocationComponent(map)
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I expect the output the symbolClickListener()